# Mobile version reputation summary background

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web

Why are the reputation points on the mobile version summary all with white background (if I've an accepted answer it is with white background too)?

My mobile OS is Android.

[image]

This is the desktop version of the reputation points summary (Access SQL left join - access removes parenthesis is green, on mobile white).

In the other sections (questions and answers) the background is correct.

This is the mobile version:

[image: Image 2]

Comment: it's a bug. i'm looking into it right now. thanks for reporting.

Comment: @Pawel: Thank you for your interest ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A fix for that is now in the repository. It should be up on the site in up to a couple of hours. Thanks again for reporting it. I will update question status once it's up.

Comment: Wow! In this moment I've checked and it's OK. Thanks